# variable does not increment for the loop in java

Tags: java

I am using the following loop to assign a value to the two dimensional array, but for some reason the i, k, and z are not incrementing; can someone please tell me why?

```
for(int i=0, k=1, z=0; i<num; i++, k+=3, z+=4)
  {

    newton[z][0]=a.re[i];
    System.out.println("newton ["+z+"]"+"[0]"+ "is " + newton[z][0]);
    System.out.println("a.re[0] is "+ a.re[0]);
    System.out.println("a.re[1] is "+a.re[1]);
    System.out.println("z is "+z);
    System.out.println("i is "+i);
    System.out.println("num is "+num);
    System.out.println("k is "+k);
    newton[z+2][0]=a.re[i];
    newton[z][1]=a.im[i];
    newton[z+2][1]=a.im[i];
    newton[z][2]=b.fre[i];
    newton[z+2][2]=b.fre[i]; 
    newton[z][3]=b.fim[i];
    newton[z+2][3]=b.fim[i];
    newton[z+k][4]=c.dre[i];
    newton[z+k][5]=c.dim[i];

  }
```

Comment: What is the value of `num`?

Comment: Your demo is too short. You should post your full program.

Comment: Can you show what output you are getting?  Is the prints doing anything?

Comment: please post code that reproduce the issue, also explain the issue by giving expected VS actual output

Comment: What makes you think that those are not incrementing?

Answer (score 3):

works for me. You are not manipulating the values of i,k,z within the loop. Hence you can test if the increments work by omitting the assignments to the array `newton`. Try this:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    for(int i=0, k=1, z=0; i<10; i++, k+=3, z+=4)
    {
        System.err.println(String.format("%d, %d, %d,", i, k, z));
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
0, 1, 0,
1, 4, 4,
2, 7, 8,
3, 10, 12,
...
```

Comment: "Works for me" should be a comment. It does not explain why the OP observes they are not incrementing. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid

Comment: That's correct. I considered posting this as a comment, but the formatting of comments is limited as far as I know. I wanted to show how it is possible to check that the variable values indeed increase.